# How to play two videos consistently using Brightcove ID?

Tags: video, brightcove

Hi i want to play two videos consistently using brightcove. Like  first time when i play the video then first video get play and after get second video automatically like in Youtube first ad get play and after get video plays. how can i achieve this using brightcove. Please provide me any idea regarding this .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to play the videos one after the other, then you can look into using a playlist with a playlist player
[Check the documentation here for info on using playlists](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/using-playlists)

You'll also want to make sure "auto advance" is selected inside the player settings to keep the content playing after the first video has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to play the next video, once the video ends, you can either create video playlist or if you have the videos separately, videos can be loaded dynamically.

You can find the implementaion and related documents here:
1. Info on method via Using playlist http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player/guides/playlist-using.html

2. Info on multiple video loaded dynamically:
   http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player/samples/multiple-video.html